# How can i circle numbers around the circular menu

Tags: html, css

I did 8 menus with the radical circle menu. But I have 8 numbers that need to surround a circle menu. I am having a bit of a problem, thought it would be a good idea to have a circle menu with numbers surrounding it, the problem that I have is that only the number circle is not placed properly, maybe I mess up something in the code, could you help me?

I am just confused about this number circle.

```css
.component {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  height: 15em;
}

.cn-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 115%;
  left: 56%;
  z-index: 11;
  margin-top: -4.5em;
  margin-left: -5em;
  padding: 0;
  width: 8em;
  height: 8em;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: none;
  background-color: #004691;
  color: #5f259f;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  border: 6px solid #fff;
}

.circle-wrapper {
  // width: 680px;
  height: 501px;
  border-radius: 51%;
  // background: Chartreuse;
  position: relative;
  // margin: 100px;
  transform: rotate(23deg);
}

.circle {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 54%;
  left: 54%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: -48px -48px -48px -53px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 51%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.deg-0 {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(251px) rotate(-65deg);
  background: #5ede29;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.deg-45 {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(251px) rotate(-110deg);
  background: #ffe816;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.deg-90 {
  transform: rotate(135deg) translate(251px) rotate(-158deg);
  background: #f74015;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.deg-135 {
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(251px) rotate(-200deg);
  background: #54bef8;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.deg-180 {
  transform: rotate(225deg) translate(251px) rotate(-248deg);
  background: #5ede29;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.deg-225 {
  transform: rotate(270deg) translate(251px) rotate(-289deg);
  background: #ffe816;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.deg-270 {
  transform: rotate(315deg) translate(251px) rotate(-338deg);
  background: #f74015;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.deg-315 {
  background: #54bef8;
  transform: rotate(360deg) translate(251px) rotate(-380deg);
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.btnDeactivated {
  background-color: #f7f4f4 !important;
  color: rgb(184 124 38);
  border: 2px solid #a57c2633 !important;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-top: -16em;
  margin-left: -15.5em;
  width: 34em;
  height: 34em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: transparent;
  /*    opacity: 0; */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
  transform: scale(0.1);
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/*cover to prevent extra space of anchors from being clickable*/
.csstransforms .cn-wrapper:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 6.2em;
  height: 6.2em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3.1em;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -3.1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  color: transparent;
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav {
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*    opacity: 0.2; */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.cn-wrapper ul {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}
.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  // margin-top: -1.3em;
  margin-left: -12em;
  width: 12em;
  height: 12em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg) skew(60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(60deg) skew(60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(60deg) skew(60deg);
  transform: rotate(60deg) skew(60deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a {
  position: absolute;
  right: -7.25em;
  bottom: -7.25em;
  display: block;
  width: 14.5em;
  height: 14.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  color: #271b1b;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 2;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-44deg) rotate(-68deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-44deg) rotate(-68deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-44deg) rotate(-68deg);
  transform: skew(-44deg) rotate(-68deg);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: auto;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a span {
  position: relative;
  top: 3.8em;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  left: -22px;
}
.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:hover {
  color: white;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a {
  top: 32px;
  transition: top 1s ease 0s;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:active,
.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:focus {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px black;
  top: 19px;
}
.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:focus {
  position: fixed; /* fix the displacement bug in webkit browsers when using tab key */
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0.3s;
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:first-child {
  transform: rotate(45deg) skew(45deg);
  background: #5ede29;
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(90deg) skew(45deg);
  background: #ffe816;
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(135deg) skew(45deg);
  background: #f74015;
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(180deg) skew(45deg);
  background: #54bef8;
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotate(225deg) skew(45deg);
  background: #5ede29;
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotate(270deg) skew(45deg);
  background: #ffe816;
}
.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(7) {
  transform: rotate(315deg) skew(45deg);
  background: #f74015;
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(8) {
  background: #54bef8;
  transform: rotate(360deg) skew(45deg);
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10em auto;
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper ul {
  display: inline-block;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li {
  float: left;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 5em;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:hover,
.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:active,
.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:focus {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li.active a {
  background-color: #6f325c;
  color: #fff;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-button {
  display: none;
}

.learn {
  transform: rotate(23deg);
}
.learn1 {
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
}

.learn2 {
  transform: rotate(-67deg);
}

.learn3 {
  transform: rotate(-112deg);
}

.learn4 {
  transform: rotate(-157deg);
}

.learn5 {
  transform: rotate(-201deg);
}

.learn6 {
  transform: rotate(-247deg);
}

.learn7 {
  transform: rotate(69deg);
}
```

```html
 <div class="component csstransforms">
          <button class="cn-button" id="cn-button">
            <img
              style="height: auto; width: 117px"
              src="../../assets/Integro-Bank-Logo-Black-background_prev_ui.c022b598.png"
              alt="logo"
            />
          </button>

          <div class="cn-wrapper opened-nav" id="cn-wrapper">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a @click="showMore" href="javascript:void(0)"
                  ><span class="learn">Learn</span></a
                >
              </li>
              <li>
                <a @click="showMore2" href="javascript:void(0)"
                  ><span class="learn1">Review</span></a
                >
              </li>
              <li>
                <a @click="showMore3" href="javascript:void(0)"
                  ><span class="learn2">Evaluate</span></a
                >
              </li>
              <li>
                <a @click="showMore4" href="javascript:void(0)"
                  ><span class="learn3">Sign-up</span></a
                >
              </li>
              <li>
                <a @click="showMore5" href="javascript:void(0)"
                  ><span class="learn4">Engage</span></a
                >
              </li>
              <li>
                <a @click="showMore6" href="javascript:void(0)"
                  ><span class="learn5">Share</span></a
                >
              </li>
              <li>
                <a @click="showMore7" href="javascript:void(0)"
                  ><span class="learn6">Impact</span></a
                >
              </li>
              <li>
                <a @click="showMore8" href="javascript:void(0)"
                  ><span class="learn7">Transform</span></a
                >
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <!-- End of Nav Structure -->
        </div>
        <div class="circle-wrapper">
          <div class="circle deg-180 btnDeactivated" id="btn1">1</div>
          <div class="circle deg-225 btnDeactivated" id="btn2">2</div>
          <div class="circle deg-270 btnDeactivated" id="btn3">3</div>
          <div class="circle deg-315 btnDeactivated" id="btn4">4</div>
          <div class="circle deg-0 btnDeactivated" id="btn5">5</div>
          <div class="circle deg-45 btnDeactivated" id="btn6">6</div>
          <div class="circle deg-90 btnDeactivated" id="btn7">7</div>
          <div class="circle deg-135 btnDeactivated" id="btn8">8</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73785209/circle-menu-surrounded-by-numbers ?

Comment: @SigurdMazanti hi the above link is removed  please can you help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite messy, but this is the closest I could get. Comments are added in the snippet below. To sum up, I added some wrappers (see HTML) and changed CSS a little bit.

Please let me know if this is good enough.

```css
.component {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  height: 15em;
  display: flex; /* Added */
  justify-content: center; /* Added */
}

/* Added */
.cn-button-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(34rem + 250px);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.cn-button {
  position: absolute;
  /* top: 115%; */ /* Removed */
  /* left: 56%; */ /* Removed */
  z-index: 11;
  /* margin-top: -4.5em; */ /* Removed */
  /* margin-left: -5em; */ /* Removed */
  padding: 0;
  width: 8em;
  height: 8em;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: none;
  background-color: #004691;
  color: #5f259f;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  border: 6px solid #fff;
}

/* Added */
.circle-wrapper-outer {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  top: 100px;
}

.circle-wrapper {
  width: 34rem; /* Added */
  height: 34rem; /* Added */
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(23deg);
  margin-left: auto;  /* Added */
  margin-right: auto;  /* Added */
  top: 0;  /* Added */
}

.circle {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 54%;
  left: 54%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: -48px -48px -48px -53px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 51%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.deg-0 {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(251px) rotate(-65deg);
  background: #5ede29;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}

/* Added */
.deg-0-new {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(325px) rotate(-65deg);
  background: #5ede29;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.deg-45 {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(251px) rotate(-110deg);
  background: #ffe816;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}

/* Added */
.deg-45-new {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(325px) rotate(-110deg);
  background: #ffe816;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.deg-90 {
  transform: rotate(135deg) translate(251px) rotate(-158deg);
  background: #f74015;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}

/* Added */
.deg-90-new {
  transform: rotate(135deg) translate(325px) rotate(-158deg);
  background: #f74015;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.deg-135 {
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(251px) rotate(-200deg);
  background: #54bef8;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}

/* Added */
.deg-135-new {
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(325px) rotate(-200deg);
  background: #54bef8;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.deg-180 {
  transform: rotate(225deg) translate(251px) rotate(-248deg);
  background: #5ede29;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}

/* Added */
.deg-180-new {
  transform: rotate(225deg) translate(305px) rotate(-248deg);
  background: #5ede29;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.deg-225 {
  transform: rotate(270deg) translate(251px) rotate(-289deg);
  background: #ffe816;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}

/* Added */
.deg-225-new {
  transform: rotate(270deg) translate(305px) rotate(-289deg);
  background: #ffe816;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.deg-270 {
  transform: rotate(315deg) translate(251px) rotate(-338deg);
  background: #f74015;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}

/* Added */
.deg-270-new {
  transform: rotate(315deg) translate(315px) rotate(-338deg);
  background: #f74015;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.deg-315 {
  background: #54bef8;
  transform: rotate(360deg) translate(251px) rotate(-380deg);
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}

/* Added */
.deg-315-new {
  background: #54bef8;
  transform: rotate(360deg) translate(325px) rotate(-380deg);
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.btnDeactivated {
  background-color: #f7f4f4 !important;
  color: rgb(184 124 38);
  border: 2px solid #a57c2633 !important;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  /* top: 100%; */ /* Removed */
  /* left: 50%; */ /* Removed */
  z-index: 10;
  top: 100px; /* Added */
  /* margin-top: -16em; */ /* Removed */
  /* margin-left: -15.5em; */ /* Removed */
  width: 34em;
  height: 34em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
  transform: scale(0.1);
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 6.2em;
  height: 6.2em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3.1em;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -3.1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  color: transparent;
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav {
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.cn-wrapper ul {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: -12em;
  width: 12em;
  height: 12em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg) skew(60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(60deg) skew(60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(60deg) skew(60deg);
  transform: rotate(60deg) skew(60deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a {
  position: absolute;
  right: -7.25em;
  bottom: -7.25em;
  display: block;
  width: 14.5em;
  height: 14.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  color: #271b1b;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 2;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-44deg) rotate(-68deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-44deg) rotate(-68deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-44deg) rotate(-68deg);
  transform: skew(-44deg) rotate(-68deg);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: auto;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a span {
  position: relative;
  top: 3.8em;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  left: -22px;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:hover {
  color: white;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a {
  top: 32px;
  transition: top 1s ease 0s;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:active,
.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:focus {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px black;
  top: 19px;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:focus {
  position: fixed;
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0.3s;
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:first-child {
  transform: rotate(45deg) skew(45deg);
  background: #5ede29;
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(90deg) skew(45deg);
  background: #ffe816;
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(135deg) skew(45deg);
  background: #f74015;
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(180deg) skew(45deg);
  background: #54bef8;
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotate(225deg) skew(45deg);
  background: #5ede29;
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotate(270deg) skew(45deg);
  background: #ffe816;
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(7) {
  transform: rotate(315deg) skew(45deg);
  background: #f74015;
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(8) {
  background: #54bef8;
  transform: rotate(360deg) skew(45deg);
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10em auto;
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper ul {
  display: inline-block;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li {
  float: left;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 5em;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:hover,
.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:active,
.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:focus {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li.active a {
  background-color: #6f325c;
  color: #fff;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-button {
  display: none;
}

.learn {
  transform: rotate(23deg);
}

.learn1 {
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
}

.learn2 {
  transform: rotate(-67deg);
}

.learn3 {
  transform: rotate(-112deg);
}

.learn4 {
  transform: rotate(-157deg);
}

.learn5 {
  transform: rotate(-201deg);
}

.learn6 {
  transform: rotate(-247deg);
}

.learn7 {
  transform: rotate(69deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="component csstransforms">
  <div class="cn-button-wrapper">
    <button class="cn-button" id="cn-button">
      <img style="height: auto; width: 117px" src="../../assets/Integro-Bank-Logo-Black-background_prev_ui.c022b598.png" alt="logo" />
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="cn-wrapper opened-nav" id="cn-wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a @click="showMore" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="learn">Learn</span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a @click="showMore2" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="learn1">Review</span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a @click="showMore3" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="learn2">Evaluate</span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a @click="showMore4" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="learn3">Sign-up</span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a @click="showMore5" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="learn4">Engage</span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a @click="showMore6" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="learn5">Share</span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a @click="showMore7" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="learn6">Impact</span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a @click="showMore8" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="learn7">Transform</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- End of Nav Structure -->
</div>

<div class="circle-wrapper-outer">
  <div class="circle-wrapper">
    <div class="circle deg-180-new btnDeactivated" id="btn1">1</div>
    <div class="circle deg-225-new btnDeactivated" id="btn2">2</div>
    <div class="circle deg-270-new btnDeactivated" id="btn3">3</div>
    <div class="circle deg-315-new btnDeactivated" id="btn4">4</div>
    <div class="circle deg-0-new btnDeactivated" id="btn5">5</div>
    <div class="circle deg-45-new btnDeactivated" id="btn6">6</div>
    <div class="circle deg-90-new btnDeactivated" id="btn7">7</div>
    <div class="circle deg-135-new btnDeactivated" id="btn8">8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Cervus thanks for the solution it is working fine, but my concern right now is responsiveness for mobile and  tablets, please can you help me out in responsive too

Comment: I'm afraid I would have to start from scratch if I wanted to make it responsive. It's not impossible, but it would take A LOT of time. As soon as you change something, something else will be broken. It's best to think about it from the start.

Comment: please can you make it  responsive